# Incompatible pointer types sending 'AVCapturePhotoSettings *' to parameter of type 'NSArray<AVCapturePhotoSettings *> * _Nonnull'

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera

I am getting the above error with the following code

```
captureOutput = [[AVCapturePhotoOutput alloc]init];
AVCapturePhotoSettings* hots = [AVCapturePhotoSettings photoSettingsWithFormat:@{AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecTypeJPEG}];

[captureOutput setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray:hots completionHandler:nil];
```

I am trying to make a barcode scanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:
`[captureOutput setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray:@[hots] completionHandler:nil];`

Comment: Works like a charm! bit now i'm having error `[AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:] Nil settings'`

this is the code causing it 
`[captureOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:settings delegate:self];`

Comment: nevermind solved it by `AVCapturePhotoSettings* settings = [[AVCapturePhotoSettings alloc] init];`